# Session is destroyed after REDIRECT by payment gateway - WORDPRESS & PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect, payment-gateway

After confirming the payment, the PG redirects the user to the response page which checking the result of the transaction. Base on the result, the response page will redirect me to either success, decline, or failed page. After the redirection, the session that holds the user and the cart information is destroyed.

```
echo 'REDIRECT=https://www.mywebsite.com/en/successful.html?transaction-number='.$transaction_number;
```

After knowing that the sessions are destroyed. I tried to save the sessions on the database but it is failed. Hope you can help me.

Comment: How do you know that the sessions are destroyed? Perhaps try `var_dump($_SESSION);` to test.

Comment: Been struggling with the same issue for weeks. Did you manage to fix the issue. @MichalJ.Figurski session is destroyed because on redirect the user is logged out of the system.  I tried using cookies but it randomly destroy session.

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski I already tried `var_dump($_SESSION);` to test

Comment: @Ritchie I am still in the midst of finding how to fix the issue.

Comment: I would place `var_dump()` followed by `exit()` (to stop code execution) in multiple places within your code to narrow down at which point the session is being destroyed. Then come back and add more details to your question.

Comment: what payment gatewy are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I solved the problem by saving the sessions data on the database, and upon redirection, I will get the current session data saved from the database.